# GridCalculatedColumn has a Property called "Expression", what can it contain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression, radgrid

GridCalculatedColumn has a Property called "Expression", what could it contain?

These are valid:

```
iif(condition, trueResult, falseResult)
{0}*{1}
Convert.ToString({0})
```

How to format the result of the expression?

e.g. this doesn't work:
iif(condition, String.Format"{0:0.00}%", {0}), "NA")

Any idea what Expression can contain?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has the same/similar rules as DataColumn.Expression, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

----Added based on comments----

See this thread on stackoverflow: [How to bind a telerik grid column to a child data object that is a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480189/how-to-bind-a-telerik-grid-column-to-a-child-data-object-that-is-a-list)

It links to:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdbindingtosubobjects.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to extend that. Just tested and it doesn't support Len and Convert methods at least.